# how to implement mixpannel analytics in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-messaging, analytics, mixpanel

i have to implement mixpannel analytics in one of my app.

i checked out Mixpannel officail site and [react-native-mixpannel](https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel)

**but i'm struggling how to get started with it.**

> How to use it from scratch and what things i need for it like firebase
>   or not ?

**Please suggest me some article or something else from where i can implement mixpannel anaylits to my react native app**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all did you use `react-native init AwesomeProject` or `expo new`?

With the first one you have access to the native code for iOS and Android.
For expo you have only the JavaScript files and **you can't use this SDK**.